# Angular - Count all dates per month & return month & count array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Basically counting records per month, where each record has a Create Date.

Need an array that contains month name + count as variables.

Only managed to do it with SQL.

Here's my array with Date Time format:

```
[
    "2021-10-06",
    "2021-10-06",
    "2021-10-06",
    "2021-10-06",
    "2021-9-06",
    "2021-9-06",
    "2021-9-06",
    "2021-9-06",
    "2021-9-06",
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for grouping month and perform count.

```js
var monthNames = [
"January", "February", "March",
"April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September",
"October", "November", "December"
];

var dates = [ "2021-10-06", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-06", "2021-9-06", "2021-9-06", "2021-9-06", "2021-9-06", "2021-9-06"];

var group = dates.reduce(function (r, o){
   var date = new Date(o); 
   var month = date.getMonth();
   var monthName = monthNames[month];
   (r[monthName]) ? r[monthName].count++ : r[monthName] = { monthName: monthName, count: 1 };
return r; 
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(group).map((key) => group[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo page](https://jsfiddle.net/9g2tq0r3/1/)

We usually use json object to solve this kind of question. Because json object could have string index.

Json:

```
{
  "10":{"cnt" : 4},
  "9":{"cnt" : 5},
}
```

Array:

```
[["10", 4],["9", 5]]
```

use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) to retrieve your array

```
var dates = [ "2021-10-06", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-06", "2021-9-06", "2021-9-06", "2021-9-06", "2021-9-06", "2021-9-06"];

let array_month = [];
for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    const month = dates[i].split('-')[2];
    array_month.push(month);
}
// array_month = ["10", "10", "10", "10", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9"]

let obj = {};
array_month.forEach(function (x) {
    // The expression counts[x] || 0 returns the value of counts[x] if it is set, otherwise 0. Then just add one and set it again in the object and the count is done.
    obj[x] = (obj[x] || 0) + 1;
});
//final = {
//  10: 4,
//  9: 5
//}

//convert object to array
var result = Object.entries(obj);
console.log(result);
//[[MonthName, MonthCount]]
//[["9", 5], ["10", 4]]
```